# Как вырезать овал по бокам блока

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой дизайн

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать по бокам такие овалы для меню сайта?

Имеется в виду этот овал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: о каком овале речь ?

Comment: Сделал правку в вопросе. Там самая нижняя картинка.

Comment: щас отвечу в первом вопросе

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:70%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 300px red; /*убрал белый цвет для большей наглядности*/
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: видоизмененный вариант из http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yefw4/

Comment: Можете показать как меняя `ширину/высоту/нужный параметр` можно менять угол скоса?

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ от @Глеб Шапошников, а именно изменение поворота искривления:

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:70%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:20% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 40% 80% 60%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 300px #5fba7d;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Играясь с процентами в `border-radius` можно менять "угол поворота" нашей кривульки.